# why some block alway in sidebar first?

Tags: users

when login and go to mysite.com/user, it have some custom block in sidebar first region, but I cant remove them in this region, why?
bookcome.module implement hook_block_view code:

```
    function bookcome_block_view($delta = '') {
    global $user;
    if ($delta === 'user-menu') {
    return array(
    'content' => _bookcome_user_menu()
    );
    } else if ($delta === 'user-menu-left') {
    return array(
    'content' => _bookcome_user_menu_left()
    );
```

and at mysite.com/admin/structure/block, the user-menu-left block status is disable, and I  am sure the current theme is using defualt theme, but the user-menu-left block alway in the sidebar first region of mysite.com/user page, would you tell me why?? how to remove them? thanks very much.

Comment: maybe you have overriden the user page with a panel and added this block in the panel?

Comment: Are you using Context Module?